# how to fix #1932 - Table does not exist in engine

Tags: php, mysql

I had to install xampp for PHP Version7.2.12 instead of php version 5.6. Before i install xampp get htdocs and mysql\data backup. After install xampp successfully I copy some data from mysql\data backup folder and paste in current mysql\data\ folder. So pasted database and table show in phpmyadmin. But, When I click table show error like following.

> 1932 - Table 'databse_name.table_name' doesn't exist in engine

Please help me to access the table normally.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I copy 10 files from backup folder mysql\data\ like aria_log.00000001, aria_log_control, auto.cnf, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ibdata1, multi-master.info, mysql.pid, mysql_error and mysql_upgrade_info and paste in current mysql\data\ folder.

Now work normally.

Comment: my database not able to recover